# CTF Reader throwing error for big files in CNTK

Tags: c++, nlp, deep-learning, cntk

I am using a CTF reader function following the CNTK tutorials on Github.

```
def create_reader(path, is_training, input_dim, label_dim):
    return MinibatchSource(CTFDeserializer(path, StreamDefs(
        features = StreamDef(field='x', shape=input_dim, is_sparse=True),
        labels = StreamDef(field='y', shape=label_dim, is_sparse=False)
    )), randomize=is_training, epoch_size= INFINITELY_REPEAT if is_training else FULL_DATA_SWEEP)
```

This works completely fine except when the input file size is bigger than a certain size (unknown). Then it throws an error like this:

```
WARNING: Sparse index value (269) at offset 8923303 in the input file (C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta6-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\common\data_pos_train_balanced_ctf.txt) exceeds the maximum expected value (268).
attempt: Reached the maximum number of allowed errors while reading the input file (C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta6-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\common\data_pos_train_balanced_ctf.txt)., retrying 2-th time out of 5...
.
.
.

RuntimeError: Reached the maximum number of allowed errors while reading the input file (C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta6-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\common\data_pos_train_balanced_ctf.txt).
```

I identified that this kind of error is being thrown in the file TextParser.cpp
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/5633e79febe1dc5147149af9190ad1944742328a/Source/Readers/CNTKTextFormatReader/TextParser.cpp

What is the solution to or work-around for this?

Comment: Sounds very much like your input file is malformed. Have a look at your input file around the offset that the error message contains: 8923303. You can, for example, skip the first 8923000 bytes of your file, via "tail -c +8923000 file.tsv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the dimensionality of your input and also know that indices start from 0. So if you created an input file mapping your vocabulary to the range 1 to 20000 the dimensionality is 20001.

Comment: I am creating the input file following the same logic. Now this fails only when the input gets large. I don't understand, if my logic was wrong, how would this have run successfully for smaller files? For example, this works fine for all input sizes up to, say, around 25K sequences. It starts failing after that.

Comment: It is possible if it is an off by one and a rare word is responsible. Do you still get the same error if you define the input dimensionality to be larger than its current value?

Comment: This was indeed the case. The input dimensionality was not updated properly. Thanks.